# Inconsistency between engines when using reluctant quantifier in negative look ahead

Tags: ruby, regex, pcre

I found something odd when using a reluctant quantifier in a negative look ahead.

When creating a regex to assert a maximum of 3 uppercase characters, I devised this:

```
^(?!(.*?[A-Z]){4}).*$
```

which works on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/VKrkeGO6EH), but not on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uE0kF4).

Why is that?

Comment: Try the regular expression with `gm` flag in [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eT4sS4)

Comment: @falsetru that was it.

Comment: FYI: It's the same for www.debuggex.com - with the 'm' modifier, it matches, whereas without it, it doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^`, `$` matches beginning/end of line in Ruby.

While in another  languages, `^`, `$` matches the beginning/end of the string unless multiline mode (`m`) is specified. (Some regular expression engine requires `g` flag to match multiple times.)

Comment: Having tried your flags suggestion, I get the impression it's more that rubular treats every line as separate input, whereas regex101 has just one input

Comment: @Bohemian, rubular's match works similar to [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

Comment: @Bohemian, According to [this result](http://rubular.com/r/88QXXZcLu1), it seems like rubular does not match line by line.

Comment: But you used the multiline flag.  If you clear the flags, you get 1 match per line.